# Ruby On Rails database --> Pretty Picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an application that can take in my db/schema.rb and my models file and produce a picture that shows the tables with relationships and also (if possible) the :dependent => :destroy mapping. (if this table gets deleted, XYZ get deleted and so on)

I have used annotate to show database columns in my model files, which is a good start, but I need a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/) produces models diagrams. I don't think it displays the :dependent => :destroy mapping, but it might be possible to patch it to add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench, if that's your DB:

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

What it is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench

The RubyMine IDE can do that too.

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Comment: Workbench produces a diagram from the database. Not difficult. It's in there. It's in front of me just now - what else can I say.

Comment: MySQL Workbench works for ruby!?  I thought it was only for PHP

Comment: MySQL Workbench works for MySQL, as the name implies. I don't understand your comment, it does not make sense? What does one have to do with another? This was about producing a diagram from the schema. The best schema can be gotten directly from the DB itself - this is where Workbench comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that can be useful to generate images of your models is [railroad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/). I don't think it handles the :dependent => :destroy mapping either, but it does have some other nice capabilities.